# Using FastAPI, I keep running into 'foo' has no attribute 'bar' problems, usually Session objects

Tags: python, asynchronous, sqlalchemy, fastapi

I'm trying to build a stock simulator with Python, FastAPI, and SQLAlchemy by following the FastAPI tutorial documentation on their website:

[FastAPI Tutorial](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/)

The following is hopefully a minimum reproducible code segment.  I made test.py to test, normally I use Uvicorn and FastAPI's OpenAPI docs.

```
def get_db():
    db = None

    try:
        db = SessionLocal()
        yield db
    finally:
        db.close()


# From crud.py
async def get_user(email: str, db: Session):
    return db.query(User).filter(email=email).all()


# From main.py
@app.get("/user")
async def get_current_user(email: str, db: Session = Depends(get_db)):
    user = await get_user(email, db)
    return User(user)

# From test.py
joe = asyncio.run(get_current_user("a@b.c"))

print(joe)
```

I keep getting this error:

> AttributeError: 'Depends' object has no attribute 'query'

I've tried so many things, including getting rid of `Depends` and using a `SessionLocal object` directly instead of having it yielded from the generator function.

I've looked at dozens of bug reports from StackOverflow, GitHub help page for FastAPI, and many others.  I've tried putting all the code on one page and hit the same wall.

When I use a database object directly:

`engine.connect.execute()`

for querying and executing SQL code, it works, but Depends isn't doing what I've read it's supposed to do.

Does anyone have any suggestions or an obvious wet fish slap?

Comment: Where did you see an example of using Depends with a SessionLocal object?  I'm not fully versed in it, but that's not a usage I've seen.

Comment: Well, @TimRoberts, I was sure FastAPI was the first place I'd seen that configuration, but it seems it was at [Towards Data Science](https://towardsdatascience.com/fastapi-cloud-database-loading-with-python-1f531f1d438a) blog.

Comment: I see it in their blog, but I can't figure out what it's supposed to do.  It doesn't make sense to me.  If it were me, I'd toss the `Depends` and come back to it later.

Comment: @TimRoberts That's what I'll do, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Why you're trying to do it this way? When you call the path operation function directly you skip the routing layer where dependencies are "injected" so you get the `Depends` class instead of the `Session` object.

Did you actually try to follow the [Async SQL tutorial](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/advanced/async-sql-databases/)?

When you use asynchronous calls all coroutines run in the same OS thread so there is on need to create a session for each request. The underlying [databases](https://www.encode.io/databases/) module is using [contextvars](https://docs.python.org/3/library/contextvars.html) to store the connection state instead.

Comment: Thank you for that clarification.  I remember reading about the single-threaded aspect of asynchronous flow in my initial studies, as well as that sessions are for dealing with threads, but somehow the bridge never connected.  It makes a lot more sense, now.

I also remember that part of the tutorial, and I remember wondering why they'd have some random other way to do things!

Comment: Upon re-reading, I see where I went wrong.  I ended up on the Async tut, then was distracted by a link to the SQLAlchemy ORM tut, which looks more like what I found in Toward Data Science.  Thanks HTF.